# How to add label to a subview?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a skscene in which i show subview and i want a "Game Over" label in it.

```
var gameoversub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

func addsubview() {
    gameoversub.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.view?.addSubview(gameoversub)
    gameoversub.center = (super.scene?.anchorPoint)!
    gameoversub.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (super.scene?.frame.size.width)!, height:(super.scene?.frame.size.height)!)
    gameoversub.addSubview(titleLabel)
}
```

It says, I can't add SKLabelNode, it wants UIView. Some solutions?

Comment: Yea use `UILabel` instead of `SKLabelNode`

Comment: It worked, thank You!